# How to get relatively durable bubbles

Tags: science-based, chemistry

How would one make a flat bubble stretched between two sides of a triangle that can withstand pressures up to at least 0.25 pounds per square inch? If it goes higher that's fine, as long as it still could be popped with a finger without much difficulty. If it requires special properties for the structures it is attached to, I can probably make that work to.

*Context for those curious:*

I'm designing a species with bat-like wings, but instead of membranes made of flesh, they can blow bubbles from organs near the wing joint that fill in the space to form the membranes when needed, and they can use their wings like hands (granted, significantly weaker and more fragile hands than those of a human) when the bubbles aren't formed. I worked out the pressure based on some research on birds and bats, but I couldn't find anything on how much pressure a bubble can withstand. The number I gave above for the pressure is actually still giving a significant error margin compared to the rough numbers I worked out (I came up with a pressure of 0.07 PPI, based on 20 square feet of wings, 45 pounds, and a rough guess that they won't be putting more than five times their weight on their wings at any point, but as noted, I left a wide error margin on that).

If I've missed any major factors you can see, feel free to point them out. If there is no way to create such a bubble under known chemistry, I'm willing to make up some sort of magic/fictional substance to solve the problem, but I'd like to do it without if I can.

Comment: Now THIS is a real-world question with a worldbuilding context and, IMO, stands as the perfect example of how and why to ask a real-world question on this Stack. I don't have a full answer yet, but you need to look into the material used to make the bubble (you won't be using water or soap...) and you need to look into the material or structure at the connection point of the bubble. I believe there's a beautifully believable answer... and it's could easily be some form of mucus (OK, call it *snot*). Or maybe a hybridization of mucus and spider silk... that would give it a lot of strength.

Comment: Liquid bubbles can only withstand tiny pressures. See http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys221core/modules/m7/surface_tension.html I presume the bubbles solidify and become solid? Even with exotic surfactants, they probably can't improve by orders of magnitude otherwise.

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/01/physicists-have-created-everlasting-bubbles/ This may serve as the nucleus of an answer or at least a handwaved explanation. That graceful failure is what all liquid bubbles lack.

Comment: Could they make cavities filled with an aerogel rather than true voids?

Comment: Hm... It's that 1/4 per in² that gives me pause. I would need to find values to really get a good answer!

Comment: The strength of a bubble is directly related to the surface tension of the fluid interface as well as its geometry. 

A round bubble is less likely to pop because sheer stresses can be pressed across the surface of the sphere, but a flat bubble like you're describing would be different.

And the amount of force that a finger can introduce to "pop" the bubble depends on if the finger is dry or wet and what's on it. if it had soap for example, it would be extremely easy to pop the bubble because the soap breaks the surface tension.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**
Wings, in the style you are after, made from any type of liquid wouldn't work.

**Long Answer (Warning Contains Science):**
The key scientific idea associated with Bubbles is surface tension. Surface tension is the energy related to expanding the surface area of a fluid, larger surfaces have more energy, and since all systems tend towards lowest energy, bubbles move to reduce their surface area.

This explains why bubbles floating in the air form spheres, because for a set volume a sphere has the smallest surface area. As to why the bubble doesn't continue to shrink is because the energy released from shrinking the bubble is equal to the energy required to compress the air contained in the bubble.

The problem with you wings is the open edge, this means that since there is no edge to support the bubble it will keep shrinking, until it forms a thin film along the supporting edges.

Unfortunately even if you have a completely enclosed shape containing the bubble it still wouldn't work. To get the best membrane you would need the material to have a high surface tension because for a given pressure it would deform the least. The material that has the highest surface tension is mercury, which has a surface tension of 0.4N/m, this informs us about the pressure range  we could get. For 0.25 Psi (1723N/m$^2$) your wings would have to be approximately kilometer lengths, which causes significant bubble and structural problems.

If you are still after using bubbles for arial transport you could use [Ballooning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballooning_(spider)) which is what spiders use to travel large distances. It works by significantly increasing the drag until it is such that the air currents can drag the creatures into the air

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

So, the organs (*main middle body*) releases material (*not sure why bubbles?*) so that it joins joints (*triangular corners*) to form wings (*as and when required*).

If wing material is popped - then a capability to self heal and reform wings. *Is this desirable ?*

Not sure why you want the wing membrane to be popped with just a finger ?

Wings (dual use - 1. hands 2. flying).
Not sure why - birds use their feet to catch their prey/food and wings to fly.
May be if feet are hurt or lost in accident, then ability to use wings as hands. Which means wing structure needs to be flexible (*triangular and flexible with decent structural strength --> ambitious *). Does this creature land, if so on what ?

This creature need a source to release this rubbery material (*preferably non sticky - so that undesirables don't stick to the wing surface*). Chemistry & Material knowledge is required to make this a feasible project.

Solution:

Is it possible to use a 3D printer in the main body to reconstruct lost membrane in the wing structure. You'll have to come up with a detection mechanism (for lost membrane).

Using 3D printer will help you experiment with the strength of the membrane.

**EDIT to make it understandable for those who still seek bubbles (replying to comment) 27/08/2022**

@Community Bot - Your comment does not say what is not clear. If you point out I can expand.

Anyways,

Firstly - Bubbles is not required as is mentioned in the original requirement. I take it as a nice to have (as it is not clear why only bubbles) but probably not required. Quite simply - why bubbles ?

Requirement is a material that can be popped with a finger (*not clear why?*), can withstand atleast 0.25 ppsi (*not clear why?*)

The way to make this project feasible is to experiment with materials that can be printed using 3D printer. 3D printer will receive prompts to reprint membrane/material that join the joints in the wing. The wing is assumed to detect missing/damaged membrane.

3D printer itself needs innovation to make it fit inside main body of the species. It is not clear how big the conceptual species is.

It is not clear whether this is a fantasy species?
Why is this species required ?

Successful conceptualisation, design, development, testing, production of this project may have huge implications depending on its application.

By the way I'm suggesting 3D printer, simply because if membrane in the wings ruptures during flight, it is imperative that the species is stabilised asap. However, there is every chance even rapid reprinting of the wing span may not be enough to save the day and the species crashes anyways.

There might be other more subtle and niche ways that I'm unaware of.

May be an alternative solution is slightly mechanical, i.e. to have a spare wing hidden inside the main body of the species, Just like we have a spare wheel inside of cars (well most of us have).

The damaged wing collapses inside the main body of the species and spare wing is deployed instantaneously. The repair of damaged wing occurs inside the main body ready to be redeployed automatically.

If I know why this species is required then I can run my mind amok.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### Colloidal Armor

Polystyrene particles suspended in a bubble can increase its mechanical strength and stability, creating a "colloidal armor". Biological polystyrene production shouldn't be too difficult to achieve, as polystyrene is an organic compound and all organisms produce polymers. These armored bubbles can also form nonspherical shapes.

Unfortunately, at your specified pressure these bubbles only maintain their structure at a diameter of roughly 1.5 millimeters. I don't see how any other form of "armor" could greatly change this value to allow for a singular strong bubble to form between two fingers. Therefore, your animal would need to produce multiple bubbles to form one wing. Surfactants can prevent these bubbles from fusing together, and at a small concentration, the presence of surfactants (such as rhamnolipid, emulsan, viscosin) will not affect the structure of your bubbles.

Acoustic waves can keep bubbles attracted to each other, so your animal could have some sort of vocal organ within their fingers to maintain wing structure. If they want to lose their bubbles to utilize their hands, they can stop producing noise from their fingers.

Information from [Probing the Mechanical Strength of an Armored Bubble and Its Implication to Particle-Stabilized Foams](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.011010), [Microstructure, Morphology, and Lifetime of Armored Bubbles Exposed to Surfactants](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/la060388x), and [Amplification of Acoustic Forces Using Microbubble Arrays Enables Manipulation of Centimeter-Scale Objects](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.128.254502)

Answer (score 0):

I get that you want bubbles... Really I do. But I want to challenge that assumption.

Have you thought about spider silk instead?

It is something with an incredibly high tensile strength to weight ratio... Meaning that it will give your creature useable wings with less weight. It fits your science tag and would even fit a hard science tag. We have GMO goats that can produce spider silk... Therefore is no limit to what creature could conceivably produce a spider silk like material.

It can be removed from the hand/wings (Not as easily as your proposed bubble... But easily enough).

Its not a bubble and your flying creature cannot pop it.. But I really think it is the best choice. Just give your terrifying bats from the underworld spinnerets and enough flexibility to weave wings along their arms and they will be ready to fly.